# iOS web app to call mobile safari share function?

Tags: ios6, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

This is a longshot, but is it possible via HTML/JavaScript e.g. For a standalone iOS web app to call the share function found in mobile safari?

E.g on a web page a user clicks a link that then calls for share to fb, twitter, email screen to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no access to that functionality from a webpage or a standalone web app. You can, of course, add FB/Twitter/etc sharing to your pages yourself.

Comment: Such a shame, would have been an awesome feature.